# Find formula for function of $n$ returning $0$ if $n$ is composite and $1$ if $n$ is prime

Tags: prime-numbers, contest-math

Sample problem:

> Find an equation $\theta(n)$ for which $\theta(n)=\left\{ \begin{array} &0, \text{when } n\in \text{Composed} \\ n, \text{when } n\in \text{Prime} \end{array} \right.$

This problem is from the International Youth Math Challenge $2018$ and since they do not return marked sheets, I am unsure if my solution was correct.

My final answer was: $$\theta (n)=n-n\cdot \text{sgn} \left(\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} |n-p_i|\right)$$ where $p_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ prime number. This is all I could come up with and to be honest, I am not too happy with it, because I feel like I have basically chosen something that will only give the answer I want. Is this solution correct, mathematically? Is there a better solution?

**Note:** $\text {sgn}(n)$ is the $\text{sign}$ or $\text{signum}$ function and $$\text{sgn}(n)=\left\{ \begin{array} &-1; \ \ n\lt 0\\ \ \ \ 0; \ \ n=0\\ \ \ \ 1; \ \ n\gt 0 \end{array} \right.$$

Comment: Are you sure you're giving the complete statement of the problem? I don't think it makes sense without some sort of restriction as to what kind of functions/primitives you are allowed to use in a solution.

Comment: The infinite product formula you suggest requires to compute an infinite product, which cannot be done in practice (and to define the signum function at $+\infty$, which is not so usual), and to know the full set of primes, which seems rather impractical as well. Easy remedies to these two defects are suggested below.

Comment: @Did which is what my title wonders. I only get the results I want, I cannot make further assumptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of functions are allowed but here is a similar one (might be equivalent after some small changes), the differences being it's finite and doesn't require ability to select primes:

For any positive integer $p$, define this function
$$
f(n,p):= \left\lceil \frac{n-p\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\rfloor}{n} \right\rceil
$$
If $p$ divides $n$ then $f(n,p)=0$, otherwise $n-p\lfloor n/p\rfloor\neq 0$ so $f(n,p)=1$.

You can then use this to make the following:
$$
\theta(n):= n - n\prod_{p=2}^{n-1}f(n,p)
$$
If $n$ is composite then one of the $p$'s will make the product $0$ and hence $\theta(n)=n$. Otherwise $n$ is prime and the product is $1$, giving $\theta(n)=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Good try; but there's something that needs fixing. When $n$ is composite, the product diverges to $\infty$; so you should define $\text {sgn} (\infty) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But, unless I am mistaken, $+\infty \gt 0?$

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Yes; just personally, I would mention that case, since often people assume that youre working in $\mathbb{R}$ instead of the extended number system. I would just put it to make sure there's no chance of getting points off.

Comment: Oh okay thank you. Ofcourse, as it is done already, I can not (and would not) update my answer. But is there any other solution for this problem? I have a suspicion that this might be an open problem, or atleast a sensible version of it will.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I am thinking about it

Comment: @Ovi I would definitely not assume we are working in $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{N}$ might be a better choice (nitpicks). I also don't see any reason to include such a definition, I would much prefer simpy choosing and noting which set does $n$ belong to. I would go as far as to consider writing $\text{sgn}(\infty)$ a mistake without well explaining why are you doing that and what do you mean by that.

Comment: @J.E Yeah I would explain that when the product diverges we denote it as equaling infinity.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the sign function, you could potentially use the **Kronecker delta**, which is defined as

$$\delta_{mn}=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }n=m\\
0 & \text{if }n\neq m
\end{cases}$$

It basically compares two numbers and gives $1$ if there is a match and $0$ otherwise. By summing over such Kronecker delta's, you could build:

$$\theta(n)=n\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\delta_{np_i}$$

(where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime number). However, I'm wondering if this would be accepted because it kind of bypasses the question of "checking if $n$ is prime". Both our formulas are just a nice rewording of the "text-form" formula given in the question, so I'm not certain this was the kind of answer that was expected.

Comment: To be honest, the entire problem seems to be a test of a student's thought process.

Answer (score 0):

Use wilsons theorem:
$$(n-1)!\equiv -1 (mod n)$$
This means that
$$\frac{(n-1)!+1}{n}$$ is an integer for prime n.
So we get that
$$\pi(\frac{(n-1)!+1}{n})$$
is an integer multiple of pi for prime n and a non-integer multiple of p for composite n. Using this we apply the cosine function to the above equation.
$$cos(\pi(\frac{(n-1)!+1}{n}))$$
Now for prime n the above is -1 or 1. For composite n the above is between -1 and 1. We want the above function to be postive, without allowing it to have a value greater than 1. So we can square it. We also want it to be 1 for prime n and 0 for composite n, so we can take the floor function. This gives us
$$\lfloor{cos^2(\pi(\frac{(n-1)!+1}{n}))}\rfloor$$
So we have a function that is zero for compostite n, and 1 for prime n, to get to what we want we simply multiply it by n. So
$$\theta(n)=\lfloor{cos^2(\pi(\frac{(n-1)!+1}{n}))}\rfloor$$